# Pick up a value above a specific value and load it against the rest of the values below

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, vba

The title of this question sounds like a conundrum so let me simplify it.

Column A
Item_1
Sub_Items
Sub_Item_1.1
Sub_Item_1.2
Sub_Item_1.3
Item_2
Sub_Items
Sub_Item_2.1
Sub_Item_2.2
Sub_Item_2.3

What I am trying to achieve by means of a formula or a macro is for each cell below "Sub_Items" put the Item number above the "Sub_Items" for the rest of the cells below it until it reached a new Item number.

**Desired Output**

Column A               Column B
 
Item_1                            Item_1
Sub_Items                     Item_1
Sub_Item_1.1                Item_1
Sub_Item_1.2                Item_1
Sub_Item_1.3               Item_1
Item_2                           Item_2
Sub_Items                    Item_2
Sub_Item_2.1              Item_2
Sub_Item_2.2              Item_2
Sub_Item_2.3              Item_2

The values against Item_1 and Sub_Items can also be blank, that is fine but I am trying to get each Item number against a corresponding sub item. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it literally "Item_1" and "Item_2", etc.?  Also, do you always know how many items you'll have, or will it change over time?

Comment: No it is not literally item_1, item_2 etc. There are  unique id's in place of item_1, item_2.. The number of items can vary. It can be maximum 1000 items (unique id's)

Comment: Can you post some sample ID's? Do you know these ahead of time, or will it change? How do you determine an ID? Is it just when you don't see "Sub_", you know that's an ID?

Comment: Please provide sample data, it might even be possible with formula

Comment: #user3578951: I cannot the actual id but it can be something like super_user_234, admin_root, etc, I know them ahead of time. In the scope of the problem I would determine the id by looking for the work "Sub_item" the value above it will be the id in all cases and the value below it will be the sub_items for that item until I find the next Item number. I will try your solution.

Comment: Hi Nimesh, I am new to stack overflow I am not sure how I can attach a sample excel file but if you could take the above example as reference, its exactly the same

Comment: you can take a screenshot of sample data and attach the image.  Can you identify the change in column A by part of the item, e.g. absence of "Sub_" from the column A (as mentioned by user3578951) ?

Comment: @user3777207 - so you get a list of the Item#s ahead of time? Is that in Excel? If so, is it in a column? We could add those to an array, and use that in the code I posted below - just some advice on how your item numbers are given to you would help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim itemTitle As String
Dim itemNo As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cel As Range, loopRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

itemTitle = "Item_" 'Your items will have at least this amount, then that starts.

Dim currentItem As String

With ws
    lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set loopRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))

    For Each cel In loopRange
        cel.Select
        If Left(cel.Value, 5) = itemTitle Then
            currentItem = cel.Value
        End If
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = currentItem
    Next cel
End With

End Sub
```

Note: I am assuming your Items will start with "Item_".  If that's not so, just change the `itemTitle` definition to whatever that might be.  This should also work for any amount of Items, whether you know how many or not.

EDIT: Ok, since your items aren't exactly "Item_1", I have a new code:

```
Sub test_with_Array()
Dim itemTitle As String
Dim itemNo As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cel As Range, loopRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet, itemNoWS As Worksheet
Dim itemNumbers() As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set itemNoWS = Sheets("Item Numbers") 'Change this to whatever the sheet is that has your unique IDs

'Now, let's find out how many unique Item IDs you have.  I am assuming they're all listed in Column A without any blank spaces.
Dim numberOfIDs As Integer
With itemNoWS
numberOfIDs = Evaluate(WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 1))))
Debug.Print "There are " & numberOfIDs & " unique IDs."
ReDim itemNumbers(1 To numberOfIDs) 'Set the array size to fit the number of unique IDs
itemNumbers() = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 1))
End With

Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(itemNumbers) To UBound(itemNumbers) 'This just checks to make sure we have the IDs
    Debug.Print itemNumbers(i, 1)
Next i

Dim currentItem As String
ws.Activate
With ws 'Now, let's add the Item Numbers by their respective entry
    lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set loopRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))

    For Each cel In loopRange
        cel.Select
        For i = LBound(itemNumbers) To UBound(itemNumbers) 'Loop through your array of Item numbers, looking for a match
            Debug.Print "Looking for " & itemNumbers(i, 1) & " in string " & cel.Value
            Debug.Print StrComp(cel.Value, itemNumbers(i, 1))
            If StrComp(cel.Value, itemNumbers(i, 1)) = 0 Then
                currentItem = cel.Value
            End If
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = currentItem
        Next i
    Next cel
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

You mentioned that you do get a list of unique IDs.  If you put these in a second worksheet in your document, call it "Item Numbers" (or something else, just be sure to change the code to reflect it), and list those items in a continuous list in Column A, the above should work.  Please let me know any tweaks/errors you have if any.

EDIT 2:

Per your note that we can use "Sub_Items" as the delimiter so to speak, try the code below:

```
Sub test()
Dim itemNo As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cel As Range, loopRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim currentItem As String

With ws
    lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Set loopRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))

    For Each cel In loopRange
        cel.Select
        If cel.Value = "Sub_Items" Then

            currentItem = cel.Offset(-1, 0).Value
            cel.Offset(-1, 1).Value = currentItem
        End If
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = currentItem
    Next cel
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

META: I'm not sure on SO how much editing/code addition is okay, so if I can make this post better for SO best practices, just let me know!

Comment: Is it possible to do this on the basis of the cell sub_items. The reason the above solution does not work is because there is no patterns in the Item name.

Comment: How can you tell an Item name from a sub name? Does the sub names have ####_[something]?  Then you would know the Item is the #####_ part?  Again, some sample data would help.  You don't have to give exact data (if it's confidential, etc.) just something like your data.

Comment: Let me try the second solution that you gave. Regarding my comment of "on the basis of the cell sub_items" what I meant is in the for loop can't we add a condition of finding the value "sub_items" and once found then select the value of the cell above the sub_items and paste it next to all the rows below until you encounter the next "sub_item". Implementation wise it may be difficult but this is what I am thinking of. Like I said trying second solution. Thanks.

Comment: This is working, not to be a prick, per row it takes 3 seconds, I have 12000 rows, roughly 10 hours, but thank you anyways. Will try to improve the performance. Thanks once again.. appreciate it.

Comment: Per row is taking 3 seconds? Hmmm....Check the code again, I turned off Screen Refreshing and calculating - that should help speed it up.  I'll work on the "Sub_Items" suggestion - that should work too.